# Image won't show up on website

Tags: html, css, image

So I'm helping my friend with her website. The website is currently up and running but two images won't show up using lightbox on a specific page.

The first two images will load properly when clicking the thumbnails. But the two on the bottom won't. I tried to access the images directly and found out that when i tried this http://www.containerwest.com/extensions/gallery/grandeprairie1.jpg (the link of the first image) it worked but not http://www.containerwest.com/extensions/gallery/grandeprairie4.jpg (the 3rd image that is supposed to work as well).

The html code is like this:

```
<table width="240" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="4">
        <col width="240">
    <col width="240">
    <col width="240">
        <tr valign="top">
        <td width="200" style="border:2px solid #FFFFFF; padding: 3px; margin: 2.5px;">
                <p align="center"><a href="../extensions/gallery/grandeprairie4.jpg" rel="lightbox[cnrl]">
             <img src="../extensions/gallery/grandeprairie4_200x200.jpg" alt="20' used container" style="width:200px;height:200px;" /> 
     </td>
         <td width="200" style="border:2px solid #FFFFFF; padding: 3px; margin: 2.5px;">
                <p align="center"><a href="../extensions/gallery/grandeprairie5.jpg" rel="lightbox[cnrl]">
             <img src="../extensions/gallery/grandeprairie5_200x200.jpg" alt="20' used container" style="width:200px;height:200px;" /> 
     </td>
```

The two images are in two cells in a table. And all the paths should be correct since all the images are under the same folder with the same dimensions(slightly different sizes though but nothing huge). The only difference is the numbers in their names.And the first two images are displayed using the same code.

I can't figure out what is wrong here since the code seems right to me. I suspect the web host and not the lightbox.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document you are looking for is under another name I believe.
http://www.containerwest.com/extensions/gallery/grandeprairie4a.JPG
Is that the image you were looking for?
Just rename it on the server and your code should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I must don't understand. She used grandeprairie4.jpg for file name. Why it turned out to be like this? And how did you find out? It's like magic.

Comment: Like Pleasure stated the website currently allows anyone to look into the folder /gallery found here http://www.containerwest.com/extensions/gallery/

I'm not sure how the "a" got added to the filename. If you don't have the ability to change the filename you can just change the code.

Comment: Sorry this might be confusing. When uploading a file to a server you specify a filename, when she uploaded the file she must have mistakenly typed an a at the end of the file.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much Patrick!

Comment: Yay I should have looked into the folder first! Feel so stupid! She insisted the file name is right so lol

Comment: So she told me she just added the a to the file name and it can be opened. Without the a it cannot. Strange as it sounds but now she can use it.

Comment: That does sound strange, glad it is working now though!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any grandeprairie4.jpg in your folder. It's either  `grandeprairie4_200x200.jpg` or `grandeprairie4a.JPG`. And please we shouldn't be able to access your folder like that : `http://www.containerwest.com/extensions/gallery/`

Comment: Thank you very much! I just tried everything i can to see if the image is in there lol

Comment: CTRL + F save lives! Please hit the "solved" button. Good luck in your work.

Comment: Thank you so much Pleasure! I feel stupid now lol

Comment: You're welcome [Solved]!

Comment: So she told me that she just added the a to the file name and it can be opened. Without the a it cannot. Strange as it sounds but now she can use it.

Answer (score -1):

You either need to change the HTML code of your page so that the a href actually references a .jpg that exists on your server, or you need to rename the appropriate existing images on the server to that stated in the code.

Comment: This answer provides no additional value over the answers already given here 10 minutes prior.